# NO PUEDO EJECUTAR CODIGO .PY

Tags: python, linux

¿Alguien sabe porque no puedo ejecutar mi codigo .py?

En la consola cuando hago ls con otros archivos .py sale de otro color.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```py
    def adivina_el_numero_computadora(x):

    print("=====================")
    print(" ¡Bienvenido al Juego! ")
    print("=====================")
    print(f"Selecciona un numero entre 1 y {x} para que la computadora intente adivinarlo")

    limite_inferios = 1
    limite_superior = x
    respuesta = ""
    
    while respuesta != "c":
    # Generar prediccion
        if limite_inferios != limite_superior:
            prediccion = random.randint(limite_inferios, limite_superior)
        else:
            prediccion = limite_inferios #tambien podria ser el superior

    # obtener respuesta usuario
    respuesta = input(f"Mi prediccion es {prediccion}. Si es muy alta, ingresa (A). Si es muy baja, ingresa (B). Si es correcta ingresa ()").lower()

    if respuesta == "a":                                 
        limite_superior = prediccion -1
    elif respuesta == "b":
        limite_inferios = prediccion + 1
    print (f"la pc lo a adivinado: {prediccion}")


      # Intervalo inicial: [1, 10]    
      # Prediccion: 6
      # Respuesta "a"
      # Intervalo: [1, 5]
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Será que no tiene el permiso de ejecución... prueba cambiándoselo con `chmod +x adivina_el_numero_pc.py`

Comment: `while respuesta != "c":` es un ciclo infinito. ¿Está bien indentado el código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta darle permisos de ejecución a tu archivo, muy posiblemente es eso. Intenta con:

```
chmod 0755 adivina_el_numero_pc.py
```

Eso debería solucionar tu problema.